# Representing execution historic with BPMN 2.0 meta-model

Tags: bpmn

I'm using BPMN2.0 meta-model to represent process models. I cannot find any attributes to keep execution historic. I'm wondering if actually BPMN 2.0 does not support that, or if something escapes me?

In other words, my question is: is it possible to represent execution historic with BPMN 2.0 meta-model? if yes, how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "execution historic"?

Comment: the process may be executed several times, by different agents, produced different results. I need to keep all this information. This is what I mean by historic execution. I want to be sure that there is no mechanism in BPMN allowing doing that before adding new classes and attributes

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to store results of each process run? Prevent from having several parallel runs at the same time? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I want to store results of each process run. My question is "does BPMN 2.0 meta-model contain concepts or attributes to do so or not?"

Comment: BTW it's BPMN language or BPMN notation. There is nothing about a meta-model here.

Comment: you can download the BPMN 2.0 specification https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/About-BPMN/ to learn about BPMN meta-model.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. To represent process model you use BPMN language/notation. Meta-model is used to describe elements of that language. It should not be a meta-model that you want to use but the notation element that you want to use. I will try to write the answer in something like 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I'm trying to develop a business process ontology from the BPMN meta-model. This is why I'm interested in the meta-model and not the notation language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BPMN supports the Elements  `Auditing` and `Monitoring`. They are meant to be hooks for auditing and monitoring related properties. For the definition of such properties the extensibility mechanism is to be used. Actual definitions are out of the scope of the specification. So, the answer is, that BPMN supports this, but leaves the details to the user or the tool vendors.